# How can I create a curved line composed of images?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I have 50 little images. All are connected each other, as in a line, sort of like a cord. I want to move one of the node images and have the rest follow along like a cord, so they become a curve.

Comment: Do you want to do this manipulation at runtime? In other words, are you trying to make your connected set of images act as if they were strung together on a rope and respond accordingly (physically) when you move one of the endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using multiple CCBezierBy/CCBezierTo instances with a CCSequence instance for all of them.

when initializing all the images have same position! and that's the starting position of your curve. then adjust position of images which come in front of others by calling `[CCSequenceInstance step:some_value]` in which some_value increases for the images that appear sooner.

you can also add this CCSquence instance to list of images actions in some update loop (and not during initialization) to make them appear in some particular order.